# Can not use a simple Action<Object> delegate to register cancellation

Tags: c#

According to the content I am reading, I should be able to register a delegate of type Action to be executed upon cancelation, but the complier gives me and error stating: 'DisplayMessage' delegate can not be used in the current context. I can not tell what I am doing wrong. 
Here is the code commented in the area, which I get the error...

I updated the code, and while Console.Writeline works, calling a message box method gives me an error stating can not convert from method group to Action delegate. Here is the updated code:

edit: The last functionality I was after was to call an actual method, one that perhaps has slightly different signature from Action. The following modification kind of works, except it prints the Window twice. I do not get why it is doing that since I am copying every line from the relevant Console.WriteLine lines in my code. I realized that I had a type mismatch between the method I wrote and what Register method accepts which is Action. Now I am basically trying to figure out what I get two MessageBoxs when the method signatures are the same, and the code is the same.

Thank you for everyone's feedback. The following code works the way I wanted. It is commented, and I am posting it in case someone else likes to do something similar.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CancellationSource
{
    internal delegate void DisplayMessage(string message);
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Count(cts.Token, 50));
            //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Count(CancellationToken.None, 50));
            Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to cancel the operation.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            Action<Object>   messageTarget;
            messageTarget = Console.WriteLine;
            cts.Token.Register(Console.WriteLine, null, true);
            messageTarget = ShowWindowsMessage;
            messageTarget ("This should print in box");
//This code opens a 
//Message box only when the called thread operation is cancelled. This code calls two different methods
//of type Action<Object> when the spawned / requested thread is canceled. 
            //cts.Token.Register(messageTarget, null, true);
            cts.Cancel();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
//Notice in order to get the method below to execute upon thread cancelation, I had to make sure its
//its signature is one of Action<Object>
        private static void ShowWindowsMessage(object value)
        {
            var message = (string)value;
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }

        private static void Count(CancellationToken token, Int32 countTo) {
            for (int count = 0; count < countTo; count++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Count is cancelled");
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(count);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Count is done");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `DisplayMessage` is a delegate type, the first argument to `Register` should be an instance of `Action<object>`. What do you want to do when the token is cancelled?

Comment: @Lee- I just want to be able to call other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using the state object because you are passing `null` then you can take another overload of the [`Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321953(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> `public CancellationTokenRegistration Register(
>       Action callback,
>       bool useSynchronizationContext
>   )`

and simply call it like this:

```
cts.Token.Register(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); }), true);
```

If you want to stick to your `delegate` you can also use this:

```
cts.Token.Register(()=> messageTarget("Hello, World!"), true);
```

EDIT:

If `Register()` demands an `Action<object>` delegate than you could just use this type and pass only the delegate name:

```
Action<object> messageTarget;
messageTarget = Console.WriteLine;
messageTarget("Hello, World!");
cts.Token.Register(messageTarget, null, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. I just hope to get one more item answered if possible, and that is to be able to call a method rather than a lambda expression. And that is why I just posted the latest update.

Comment: @maverick if you declare `messageTarget` as an `Action<object>` delegate you can pass just the name of it to `Register`. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

This declares new delegate *type*, `DisplayMessage`:

```
internal delegate void DisplayMessage(string message);
```

You don't need new delegate *type*. You need new *instance* of delegate.
Just declare a method, which signature matches `Action<object>` signature, and use method group syntax:

```
internal static class Program
{
    // ...

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ...

        // this line is equivalent of
        // cts.Token.Register(new Action<object>(OnCancelled), null, true);
        cts.Token.Register(OnCancelled, null, true);
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    static void OnCancelled(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: He's already having a method pointed to by `messageTarget`: `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @haim770: how is this related to answer?

Comment: @haim770 & Dennis-Thanks. This helps to know I have a shorter way and can have options. I got the DisplayMessage part from MSDN, and it that code there is an if statement, which assigns different actions to messageTarget.